# Python tensorflow throwing a 'module not found' error for ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conda, ctypes

I've been playing around with the SIMPLE project (https://medium.com/applied-data-science/how-to-train-ai-agents-to-play-multiplayer-games-using-self-play-deep-reinforcement-learning-247d0b440717) in an attempt to better understand using ML for multi-player games. The project is a few years old, so I decided to try updating the dependencies to newer versions. My requirements.txt now looks like this:

```
pytorch==2.0.1
pytorch-cuda==11.8
tensorflow==2.10.0
stable-baselines3==1.5.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyterlab==4.0.2
pillow
mpi4py==3.1.4
```

I used conda to create a python 3.10 environment and installed the dependencies. Everything installed, and there were no errors flagged in pycharm, so I went ahead and ran train.py . The run immediately crashed with the error:

```
C:\workspace\SIMPLE\app\train.py -r -e sushigo 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\SIMPLE\app\train.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "E:\anaconda3\envs\SIMPLE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "E:\anaconda3\envs\SIMPLE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "E:\anaconda3\envs\SIMPLE\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried clean installs of the libraries. I tried completely uninstalling anaconda and starting from scratch. I tried installing just the first 4 libraries to eliminate potential conflicts. No matter what, I always end up with that same error. I'm not sure what else to do at this point. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

**System Info**:

Windows 10 (64 bit)

Python 3.10.8

conda 23.5.0

PyCharm 2023.1.3 (Community Edition)

Comment: The [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) say that you need to install [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170). Did you do that?

Comment: @justhecuke I do have the MSVC installed. One thing I did notice in those instructions was enabling long path support for Windows. From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do that in non-enterprise versions of Windows. Is that step actually important or can I ignore it?

Comment: Have you tried using `venv` rather than anaconda? I'm honestly not a big fan of anaconda and have had a lot of issues setting it up for my wife on windows machines, especially in non-default locations. and perhaps trying using pip to install the dependencies directly, without version tags. and then use pip to print out the versions later.

Comment: @justhecuke I ended up creating another environment that seems to have worked. I suspect the issue may have been that I installed pytorch first rather than just letting tensorflow install it as a dependency. That said, I did run into other issues, and installing with pip seemed to clear those up.

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted out now. These packages engage in some questionable module-level logic which can easily cause problems.